# How to direct Hibernate logger statements in different log files for different applications using jboss-log4j.xml file

Tags: hibernate, logging, jboss, log4j

I am using JBOSS 4.2.2 server to deploy multiple web applications. Each application uses Hibernate and for each application there are separate log files and separate appenders. Now for Hibernate logging statements of one application should go in log file of that particular application. Does anybody know how to configure log4j.xml file to achieve this?

Comment: To clarify the question: JBossAS uses log4j for its own logging, so an app deployed on the server cannot configure log4j for its own use (at least not easily, IIRC). The "recommended" approach is for all apps to add their logging configurations to jboss-log4j.xml. If two apps use hibernate, all org.hibernate category logs from either of them will go to the same appender. Milind wants them to go to different log files.

Answer (score 2):

In JBoss you can use the TCL filter as described [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SeparatingApplicationLogs). Just add the filter to the part of the configuration you want to manipulate.

Example (slightly adapted from above source, look at section *Deploy Application As .war File*):

```
<appender name="App1Log" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler" />
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/app1.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%8.8t][%20.20c] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.jboss.logging.filter.TCLFilter">
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
        <param name="DeployURL" value="app1-exp.war"/>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple applications each running hibernate just create an appender for hibernate in the application log4j.xml file with the classpath of the hibernate classes i.e org.hibernate and this should direct the output to the specified log file.

If that does not work check that hibernate is not picking up a log4j properties file that has been bundled into any of your library jars. If hibernate fails to find the log4j.xml file then you should get a warning message in system.out

karl

Comment: I guess the question is how to split org.hibernate log messages between different log files for each web application.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understand your problem correctly. I assume you want to direct output from the same logger to different files depending on the application that issues the log statement.

Log4J provides a [Mapped Diagnostic context](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html). This context can be set to a different value (depending on your application) before the hibernate code runs.  Each log-statement issued by hibernate then also contains the contents of the MDC.

With that you can write a special appender that inspects the contents of the MDC and writes the log message to different files.

I have used this approach in a heavy multi-threaded application where every thread produces its own log-file and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding an NDC. The logs still go to the same file, but the file will be lot easier to grep.
2. Change the JBoss classloading such that each application can have its own log4j.xml